# How to combign callable Enum with MultiValueEnum (aenum)

Tags: python

I am trying to use a callable Enum to do natural language interpolation of simple functions. This means my Enum needs to be fetched with a token, but also hold a lambda function for use.

I found code as follows to make the callable aspect I needed;

```
class FuncEnum(Enum):
    def __init__(self, val, func=None):
        self.val = val
        self.func = func or (lambda x, y: None)
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
```

But, I also need to retrieve the enum using its first value. Doing this typically requires aenum.

```
class Operators(FuncEnum):
    ADD = ('+', lambda x, y: x+y)
    SUB = ('-', lambda x, y: x-y)
    MULT = ('*', lambda x, y: x*y)
    DIV = ('/', lambda x, y: x/y)

    @staticmethod
    def do(token, x, y):
        opr = Operators(token)
        return opr(x,y)
```

tldr; I need my 'do' method to work

I know these four can be simplified, but I'm looking to add more once these four work for more complicated operations.

Comment: why use an enum instead of a dictionary? I think this is overengineered. Can you explain the expected program flow?

Comment: Above this is code to read in and parse 'natural' language, looking for key symbols to denote an equasion. When it finds one, it attempts to make tokens of the string (including these operations) and push them onto a stack for later evaluation.

Comment: Does it matter that the name used to look up the enumerators be the class name itself?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question, but if so, no it does not matter. Only that it can be found via the first value, and invoked with the second (lambda function)